# SML/NJ - linked list which can hold any types

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I trying to create a datatype for linked list which can hold all types at same time i.e linked list of void* elements  , the designing is to create a `Node` datatype which hold a record contains `Value` and `Next`  .

What I did so far is   -

```
datatype 'a anything = dummy of 'a ; (* suppose to hold any type (i.e void*) *)

datatype linkedList = Node of {Value:dummy, Next:linkedList}; (* Node contain this record *)
```

As you can see the above trying does not works out , but I believe my idea is clear enough  , so what changes are required here to make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are being forced to use a record type. Because otherwise I think it is simpler to do:

```
datatype 'a linkedlist = Empty | Cons of 'a * 'a linkedlist
```

Then you can use it somewhat like:

```
val jedis = Cons ("Obi-wan", Cons("Luke", Cons("Yoda", Cons("Anakin", Empty))));
```

I think the use of the record is a poor choice here. I cannot even think how I could represent an empty list with that approach.

**-EDIT-**

To answer your comment about supporting multiple types:

```
datatype polymorphic = N of int | S of string | B of bool
Cons(S("A"), Cons(N(5), Cons(N(6), Cons(B(true), Empty))));
```

Given the circumstances you may prefer SML lists instead:

```
S("A")::N(5)::N(6)::B(true)::[];
```

Which produces the list

```
[S "A",N 5,N 6,B true]
```

That is, a list of the same type (i.e. polymorphic), but this type  is capable of containing different kinds of things through its multiple constructors.

Comment: I meant linked list which hold multiple type at same time  , like - `["A" , 5 , 6 , true]`

Comment: You cannot put just any arbitrary type in any datatype structure in SML because it is statically typed. If you know what you want to put on it, you can define a datatype to represent it. See my edition of the answer for an example.

Comment: So according to what you say  , in **SML** there is no something similar to `void*`  ?

Comment: SML is a strongly typed language. You design and define your types statically and the compiler makes sure your code obeys the rules of the type system. Lists in SML can only contain elements of one type. So, if you want your list to contain different kinds of things you have to encapsulate them all in a datatype which you can later use in a list.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, if it is important that the types of your polymorphic list remain open, you can use SML's built-in exception type: exn. The exn type is open and can be extended anywhere in the program.

```
exception INT of int
exception STR of string
val xs = [STR "A", INT 5, INT 6] : exn list
```

You can case selectively on particular types as usual:

```
val inc_ints = List.map (fn INT i => INT (i + 1) | other => other)
```

And you can later extend the type without mention of its previous definition:

```
exception BOOL of bool
val ys = [STR "A", INT 5, INT 6, BOOL true] : exn list
```

Notice that you can put the construction of any exception in there (here the div-by-zero exception):

```
val zs = Div :: ys : exn list
```

That said, this (ab)use really has very few good use cases and you are generally better off with a closed sum type as explained by Edwin in the answer above.